# Functions for creating and reshaping big data in R using the FF package

Tags: r, bigdata, reshape, ff, ffbase

I'm new to R and the FF package, and am trying to better understand how FF allows users to work with large datasets (>4Gb). I have spent a considerable amount of time trawling the web for tutorials, but the ones I could find generally go over my head.

I learn best by doing, so as an exercise, I would like to know how to create a long-format time-series dataset, similar to R's in-built "Indometh" dataset, using arbitrary values. Then I would like to reshape it into wide format. Then I would like to save the output as a csv file.

With small datasets this is simple, and can be achieved using the following script:

```
##########################################
#Generate the data frame

DF<-data.frame()
for(Subject in 1:6){
  for(time in 1:11){
    DF<-rbind(DF,c(Subject,time,runif(1)))
  }
}
names(DF)<-c("Subject","time","conc")

##########################################
#Reshape to wide format

DF<-reshape(DF, v.names = "conc", idvar = "Subject", timevar = "time", direction = "wide")

##########################################
#Save csv file

write.csv(DF,file="DF.csv")
```

But I would like to learn to do this for file sizes of approximately 10 Gb. How would I do this using the FF package? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `reshape` does not explicitly exists for ffdf objects. But it is quite straightforward to execute with functionality from package `ffbase`. Just use ffdfdply from package `ffbase`, split by Subject and apply `reshape` inside the function.

An example on the Indometh dataset with 1000000 subjects.

```
require(ffbase)
require(datasets)
data(Indometh)

## Generate some random data
x <- expand.ffgrid(Subject = ff(factor(1:1000000)), time = ff(unique(Indometh$time)))
x$conc <- ffrandom(n=nrow(x), rfun = rnorm)
dim(x)
[1] 11000000        3

## and reshape to wide format
result <- ffdfdply(x=x, split=x$Subject, FUN=function(datawithseveralsplitelements){
  df <- reshape(datawithseveralsplitelements, 
              v.names = "conc", idvar = "Subject", timevar = "time", direction = "wide")
  as.data.frame(df)
})
class(result)
[1] "ffdf"
colnames(result)
[1] "Subject"   "conc.0.25" "conc.0.5"  "conc.0.75" "conc.1"    "conc.1.25" "conc.2"    "conc.3"    "conc.4"    "conc.5"    "conc.6"    "conc.8"   
dim(result)
[1] 1000000      12
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be hard put to construct a less efficient method than what you offer. Using rbind.data.frame is incredibly inefficient.  Try this instead to create a six thousand line dataset for 6 subjects:

```
DF <- data.frame( Subj = rep( 1:6, each=1000), matrix(runif(6000*11), nrow=6000) )
```

Scaling it up to have a billion items (US billion, not UK billion) should give you about an 10GB object, so maybe trying 80 million lines or so?

I think asking for a tutorial in the ff-package is out-of-scope for SO. Please read the FAQ. Such questions are generally closed because the questioner demonstrates that they don't really know what they are talking about.

Comment: Second, You have obviously not read my question. I did not ask for a tutorial in the ff-package. I asked how to do a very specific task. Your answer shows that you do not understand how to do that task.

Comment: Well, I did read the question as can be seen by my efforts at coding. But I admit to not knowing about the incredibly compact solution that jwiffels provided with `ffdfdply`. So I guess I'll just upvote you both.