# Reshape ffdf dataframe in R

Tags: r, reshape2, ff, ffbase

I am using `dcast` function to rshape datframe in `R`,
but while using large dataframe. I converted that into `ffdf dataframe` unable to use `dcast` function please help me if any alternatives. Find the below example i used for small dataframe and what i want to do for `ffdf dataframe`:

```
- hdsample <- read.csv("C:/Users/PK5016573/Desktop/hdsample.csv")
- View(hdsample)


hd<-dcast(hhpsample,MemberID~Year+Specialty+ProcedureGroup+Vendor+PlaceSvc+PCP+PrimaryConditionGroup+CharlsonIndex)
```

This is working but:

```
hhp<-read.ffdf("C:/Users/PK5016573/Desktop/hdsample.csv")

hd<-dcast(hhpsample,MemberID~Year+Specialty+ProcedureGroup+Vendor+PlaceSvc+PCP+PrimaryConditionGroup+CharlsonIndex)
```

This gives me error please help

thanks in advance
pavan kancharala

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi akrun please downlad data from the url:http://www.heritagehealthprize.com/c/hhp/data   after downloading sort it in excel take only two MemberID data try first example after that take all the data and try the second code u will find the error

Comment: Is it `HHP_release1`?

Comment: ya claims dataset HHP_release3

Comment: Use ffdfdply from package ffbase and inside the FUN, apply dcast.data.table. Similar example shown here which uses reshape inside FUN. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472459/functions-for-creating-and-reshaping-big-data-in-r-using-the-ff-package/21478168#21478168

Comment: Hi @jwijffels I tried it but not working can u give detail explination please thanks :)

Comment: The objective of stackoverflow is that you provide a reproducible example and that others can help you where you are stuck. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this question but it may not work largely factored data

```
# Reshape_function to process on data
   # Reshaping data as per year and Primary condition group
    library(reshape2)
    library(ffbase)
    reshapefunction<-function(x){
    df=dcast(x,MemberID~ Year+PrimaryConditionGroup,
    value.var= "rep.x..each...2668990.",              
    fun.aggregate = sum)
    }
    # Reshaping data using reshape_function 
    # Specifying size of chunks to process the data
    PrimaryConditionGroup<-ffdfdply(x=hhp,split=hhp$MemberID
    ,FUN = function(x) reshapefunction(x),BATCHBYTES = 100000000,trace=TRUE)

View(PrimaryConditionGroup)
```

All the data was taken from kaggle competition added one more column **"rep.x..each...2668990."** which contains 1 in every row used for aggregation purpose